# Can I travel within the US with reinstated I-20 and valid F-1 visa?

Tags: air-travel, airports, tsa, domestic-travel

I have an F-1 international student visa which is still valid, and my passport is still valid, my I-20 is reinstated and my case is in the process. Can I still fly within the US? Will TSA agent ask about my I-20?

Comment: TSA agents don't care about your immigration status (at least not as part of their job). Show your boarding pass and valid photo-ID (even if that's the main page in your passport) and don't worry about it.

Comment: "my I-20 is reinstated and my case is in the process" What is in process? If your F1 reinstatement is still pending, you have not been reinstated.

Answer (score 2):

They only check an ID like the driver's license or a state ID or if you dont have either, then your passport. At no point will your visa (don't even bother about your I-20) be checked for domestic travel (assuming you are inside the US right now).